# How to convert a query with left joins with multiple "on conditions" to a view in postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, view, materialized-views

Consider the query below(very small example for brevity)

```sql
select * from users u
left join orders o on (u.oid = o.id and o.state='CA') -- 'CA' aka state code will be passed dynamically
where u.id in (1,2,3)
```

How to convert this query to a view? In my java code currently the userIds and state is dynamic. Meaning for each request I am getting a different set of userIds and state and then I am forming the above query to get the results.

But for performance/other reasons, I want to convert this query to a materialized view or at the very least a normal view.

The main problem is that the state is being passed in the "on" condition. If this wasn't dynamic, then query would be like so

```sql
select * from users u
left join orders o on (u.oid = o.id) -- if state code filter wasn't present/required at all in business requirements
where u.id in (1,2,3)
```

And then this could've been easily converted to a view and I could've run the query as

```sql
select * from my_custom_view where user_id in (1,2,3)
```

But since, state is being passed dynamically inside the "on" condition, I am not sure how to convert this to a view(both for organization and later on for performance purposes through materialized view etc).

Comment: `SELECT * FROM my_custom_view WHERE user_id in (1,2,3)
AND (state = 'CA' OR state IS NULL);` should work

Comment: Unfortunately that wouldnt work for me because state can be something like 'xyz' in which case with left join I would get null rows(which is what I want), but if I move it to where clause like you said, I will not get any results back.

Comment: Filter the view with `oid = id and state=<parameter> OR id is null and state is null` -- What's the problem with this?

Comment: @TheImpaler do you mean to move the foreign key check (u.oid = o.id) from left join's on condition to the "where" clause filter? In that case, how will I left join with orders table in the first place? just do `left join orders o on true`?

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you want to query and filter a view (since it probably preprocesses data) and this view has an outer join.

If you were not using a view your "Plain Query" would look like:

```sql
select u.*, o.id as xid, o.state, o.price
from users u
left join orders o on u.oid = o.id and state = 'CA'
where u.id in (1, 2, 3);
```

Removing the extra predicate `state = 'CA'` the view is created as:

```sql
create view v as
select u.id as user_id, u.oid as order_id, o.state as state from users u
join orders o on (u.oid = o.id) -- removed LEFT JOIN
where u.id in (10)
union all -- added LEFT JOIN separately
select u.id as user_id, u.oid as order_id, null from users u
where u.id in (10)
```

To query this view and get the same result you need to account for the outer join. Instead of adding the predicate `state = 'CA'` to it you need to add the predicate `state = 'CA' or state is null` to it.

This time, the "Query Through a View" will take the form:

```sql
select * from v where state = 'CA' or state is null;
```

You can see that both options -- plain query and query through a view -- produce the same result according to the left join.

See running example at [DB fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4gU5ihQutqra79cJKx31jr/19).

Comment: note that user can multiple orders and user table has duplicate data(kind of). This is same approach as frank and I already mentioned why it wouldnt work. Using left join, at least I will get user data back with orders being null. But with where clause like you mentioned, I will loose user data as well. I have added a fiddle example here(2nd query returns no results): https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4gU5ihQutqra79cJKx31jr/21

Comment: See updated solution. It was trickier than anticipated. Good question!